# How do I use Django Dynamic Formset and Select2 together in the same page?

Tags: jquery, django, templates, jquery-select2, formset

I have successfully used Django Dynamic Formset and Select2 separately. However, when I am using select2 and adding more forms in my formset dynamically, the added forms wouldn't work for the dropdowns. I click on them but the dropdowns wouldn't open.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.trt').formset();
    });

    $('select').select2();
</script>
```

How can I edit the above code so that select2 works for my added forms?

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me is adding an on.click statement to call the select2 for the class .add-row after the formset script at the end of the document. Like this:

```
<script>
$( ".add-row" ).click(function() {
  $('.forselect2').select2();
});
</script>
```

Not sure if its still relevant for you just added in case someone also finds this. For your case, just replace '.forselect2' with 'select2' and see if it works.

Comment: It still works for me. Please elaborate why you think it won’t.

Comment: This will work only once , after more than 2 dynamic element event trigger before option  added to inline select box.  or sometime it will conflict with other JS event .  There is event called formset:added for this

Comment: It works for me adding multiple elements, never tried it with more then ten though, each time the select box populates correctly. I am not using this with inline admin form though, just for a regular form or formset.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you from my personal experience that Django-Dynamic-Formset doesn't behave well with other apps/tools on the same field. In some cases lots of alteration is needed to get it to work when other JS is present.

Take a look at this: (this one is using django_select2 and not select2)
https://github.com/anneFly/django-dynamic-formset-select2-poc

It hasn't been updated for a while but you can see at the end it addresses some of the conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else wants this, using inspiration from [here](https://github.com/anneFly/django-dynamic-formset-select2-poc), this solution worked for me using the standard JQuery, formset.js and select2, for n additional rows:

```
<script src='{% static "js/jquery.formset.js" %}'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
        addText: 'add another',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
        added: function($row) {
            $('#id_allowance-'+$row[0].rowIndex+'-accounts').select2({ width:'resolve'});
        }
    });
</script>
```

You will need to change the id concatenation function to match your own id pattern.

Answer (score 1):

for thoose who still having this issue i have found a diffrent solution:
check if the empty form element has select2 initialized in its select input
if it is then destroy it using

```
$('your_empty_form').find('select').select2('destroy')
```

after destroying select2 clone that form and reinitialize select2 on that input

```
let newSelectEl = (`#id_your-${prefix}-id`)
newSelectEl.select2()
```

that fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this code  for django inline admin form

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

      django.jQuery(document).on('formset:added', function(event, $row, formsetName) { 
           if (formsetName == 'usereds_set'   ){
              $(".inline-related #id_"+$row.attr('id')+ "-eds" ).select2({ width:'resolve'});   
           } 
      });


 </script>
```

**Note 1 :** include select2 js/css in your  body

**Note 2:** change formsetName  condition in code

Answer (score 0):

Done with SetTimeout(). Set select2() to all select components after 100ms of delay

Answer (score 0):

I could get Django dynamic formsets to work finally after a good amount of debugging.

If the empty form is hidden (which will be the case) and you invoke select2 on empty forms, it doesn't render properly. Try to **invoke select2 only on visible select fields**.

So, if your classname is multiselectbox, try to use something like this:

```
$('.multiselectbox:visible').select2();
```